# Attempting a quicksort, returns TypeError.

Tags: python, list, sorting, nonetype

```
names = ['James','Adam','Ross','Bryce','Sue','Matt','Chris','Sarah','Rachel','Aron']

def sort(names):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []
    if len(names) > 1:
        pivot = names[0]
        for x in names:
            if x < pivot:
                str(less.append(x))
            elif x == pivot:
                str(equal.append(x))
            elif x > pivot:
                str(greater.append(x))
        return sort(less) + sort(equal) + sort(greater)
    else:
        if len(names) == 1:
            return names                            
print sort(names)
```

Whenever I run this, it returns this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'.
```

Can somebody tell me what is up with this? I'm quite new to Python

Comment: Just a tip, since everything in your `equal` list is equal to the pivot, it doesn't need to be sorted, and can be simply added into the center such that you have `return sort(less) + equal + sort(greater)`

Comment: another tip, quick-sort have the benefit of being an 'in-place' sort. so it can be done inside a single list by swapping values. This code in contrast, is creating loads of new lists as the recursion happens.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add a list to a `None` type, as the error says. It's happening on line 16 of the code sample you have.

But let's look at these lines:

```
pivot = names[0]
for x in names:
    if x < pivot:
        str(less.append(x))
```

Since you say you're new to Python, I'll explain. When you say `x < pivot` you're not asking it whether it comes before it in the list or not, you making a  lexicographical comparison. For example, in Python we have:

```
>>> 'a' < 'b'
True
```

Secondly, the `str(less.append(x))` doesn't do anything either. You're asking it to make a string out of a list operation. It will return a `None` type. Like this:

```
>>> less = []
>>> str(less.append('hi'))
'None'
```

So, at the end of all your stuff, the issue is that your function returns nothing since you don't take into account when the list is of length 0.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for the 0 size list:

```
names = ['James','Adam','Ross','Bryce','Sue','Matt','Chris','Sarah','Rachel','Aron']

def sort(names):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []
    if len(names) > 1:
        pivot = names[0]
        for x in names:
            if x < pivot:
                str(less.append(x))
            elif x == pivot:
                str(equal.append(x))
            elif x > pivot:
                str(greater.append(x))
        return sort(less) + sort(equal) + sort(greater)
    else:
        if len(names) == 1 or len(names) == 0:
            return names            

print sort(names)
```

Comment: This is important, because there are cases `sort` will be called with empty list as argument. when that happens, the original code returns a 'NoneType' instead of a list. that result + with other result which returns a proper list cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Like all functions in python, your sort function returns None when it does not explicitly return something. Since you are new to python, try playing with lists in the IDE first,then do your algorithm.

```
some_list = [1,2,3,4]
an_index = some_list.index(1)
some_list.append(5) #adding at the end of list
```

The documentation is a very good place to start: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an empty list, which `less` will be in this case, returns `None`.